# Insert input value into two different tables with the same userId

Tags: php, mysqli

I need to send the values of username, password, mail, first name and last name into two different tables in my database. I have made that possible with this code, and i get the values correct. I have one problem tho. When the user-info goes into "users" table, it auto-generates one userId. That same userId i need to use and put into the other table "usermeta" to connect the information to the correct user. What happens now is that i get a userId in the users table, but in the usermeta table the userId is = 0 on all new users. Can anyone help me?

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset ($_POST['password'])) {
    $username   = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password   = md5($mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
    $email      = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['mail']);
    $fname      = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
    $lname      = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);

    $query = <<<END
    INSERT INTO users(username,pass,email,admin)
    VALUES('{$username}','{$password}','{$email}','{$_POST['admin']}')
END;

    $q = <<<END
    INSERT INTO usermeta(first_name,last_name)
    VALUES('{$fname}','{$lname}')
END;

if ($mysqli->query($query) !== TRUE) {
    die("Could not query database" . $mysqli->errno . " : " . $mysqli->error);
    }
if ( $mysqli->query($q) !== TRUE) {
    die("Could not query database" . $mysqli->errno . " : " . $mysqli->error);
    header('Location:home.php');
    } 
}
```

I got a form further down in the code that the info comes from that's going to the database, but it's the php-code that makes the error i assume to i exclude that code.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I've tried to implement your different comments. Thanks alot for the answers!
If i try to get the latest id inbetween the $query and $q, the output is 0. If i use the command:

```
if ($mysqli->query($query) === TRUE) {
    $last_id = $mysqli->insert_id;
    echo $last_id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
}
```

I get the correct id. But how can i use that variable to the new $q? It seems that the function breaks after the if is done.

Thanks! :)

Comment: You should use parameterized queries. You also should not use `md5` for hashing.  `$_POST['admin']` is an example of why the escaping is not the best choice. Use the last insert id function to get the ID of your first insert.

Comment: Don't use `md5` for password hashing. Use `password_hash` for creating hashed passwords for save, then `password_verify` for verifying that a user's entered password matches the saved hash. Also, do not escape the user's entered password prior to hashing.

Comment: You can get the ID created by the insert with insert_id: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to retrieve the value of the auto-increment id that was created in your last insert.  ([Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) here)

So try:

```
$q = <<<END

INSERT INTO usermeta(first_name,last_name, userId)
VALUES('{$fname}','{$lname}', LAST_INSERT_ID();)
END;
```

Comment: This code gave me a syntax error. It was probably me who did something wrong but managed to make it work in a similar way. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Okey i managed to get it done. Thanks guys for the help!

The working code looks like this:

```
$query = <<<END
INSERT INTO users(username,pass,email,admin)
VALUES('{$username}','{$password}','{$email}','{$_POST['admin']}')
END;

if ($mysqli->query($query) === TRUE) {
    $last_id = $mysqli->insert_id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
}

$q = <<<END
INSERT INTO usermeta(first_name,last_name, user_id)
VALUES('{$fname}','{$lname}','{$last_id}')
END;

if ($mysqli->query($q) !== TRUE) {
    die("Could not query database" . $mysqli->errno . " : " . $mysqli->error);
}
```